# A question about AP.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

[image]

How is the encircled step justifiable? According to my knowledge I can substitute m=any variable but how can I substitute m=2m-1, isn't it the same as assuming m=1?

Comment: Substitute $m=$ any other variable (say, $\xi$), then erase all previous lines containing $m$, then substitute $\xi=2m-1$. In effect, that's what they do.

Comment: The author meant to *replace* any occurrence of $m$ by $2m-1$. I think it is a bad notation to write this like $m=2m-1$ because one is temped to interpret it as an equation and conclude $m=1$. I prefer $m\mapsto 2m-1$ or $m\to 2m-1$. It would be even better to use a new variable to avoid confusion: $m\mapsto 2\mu-1$. Here equality would be a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

After you are convinced with

$$ \frac{2a+(m-1)d}{2a+(n-1)d}=\frac{m}{n} $$

Simply, Cross multiply it to get,

$$ 2an + n(m-1)d = 2am + m(n-1)d $$

$$ \implies \require{cancel} \cancel{ (m-n)} d = 2a\cancel{(m-n)} $$

$$ \implies d= 2a $$

Now it is obvious to find the ratio of $m^{th}:n^{th}$ terms' ratio.

$ \frac{m^{th} \ \text{term}}{n^{th} \ \text{term}} = \frac{a+(m-1)2a}{a+(n-1)2a} $ [ Since $d=2a$]

$$ = \frac{1+(2m-2)}{1+(2n-2)} = \frac{(2m-1)}{(2n-1)} \square $$

Comment: in the second equation you forgot $d$ in the R.H.S. $2am+m(n-1)d$

Comment: @mettled mike Oops! You are right :)

Comment: Any more queries?

Comment: no, I like your answer! But I still want to know if the substitution made in my question's answer is correct or not.

Comment: @mettled mike I am working on that, however it may be the case that in the solution, the method that is printed is an advanced method. But I'll see it..!

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac mn=\dfrac{a+d\cdot\dfrac{m-1}2}{a+d\cdot\dfrac{n-1}2}$$

Substitute $\dfrac{m-1}2=M-1\iff m=2M-1,\dfrac{n-1}2=N-1$

to find the ratio of $M,N$ terms

No confusion, I hope

Comment: but you are substituting a different variable and I'll get the ratio in terms of $M$ and $N$ not $m$ and $n$. You haven't addressed my question.

Comment: @mettledmike, Now you can safely without confusion replace $M,N$ with $$m,n$$ respectively.

Comment: that just gives back the original ratio.

Answer (score 0):

In equation 1 we have obtained a relationship that any 2 quantities, m and n when taken in ratio,
$\frac{(2a + (m-1)d)}{(2a + (n-1)d)}  =  \frac{(m)}{(n)}$
are of the form of LHS in eq1.
After that we see what happens when the two quantities are of the form 2m-1 and 2n-1 we just replace m and n with the corresponding new forms. We don't actually consider them equal. 
For example 3 is a number of the form 2m-1 where m is 2. But 4 isn't of the form 2m-1, not for m being an integer.

Comment: Why isn't​ my mathjax code working? Can anyone help please

Comment: use \ not / (backward slash instead of forward)

Answer (score 0):

If a statement is true for every m and n, it is also true for 2m-1 and 2n-1. For example from (m + n)^2 = m^2 + n^2 + 2mn, we get (2m+2n-2)^2 = (2m-1)^2 + (2n-1)^2 + 2(2m-1)(2n-1).

Comment: that's actually not true. for example, $(m+n)^2=m^2+n^2+2mn$ but $[(2m-1)^2+(2n-1)]^2=4m^2+4n^2-8m-8n+8mn+3$

Answer (score 0):

The question itself is confusing. What it means is that the condition is true for any $m,n$ you care to choose, rather than a specific $m,n$.

Given that it is true for any $m,n$ it is somewhat confusing to use the same symbols in the suggested answer, as has been done.

Maybe clearer to say that if it is true for any $m,n$ then we can pick the specific values $m=2r-1, n=2t-1$ and go from there.

It doesn't matter what you call your variables - you can give them what names you like. So having worked out an expression in $r,t$, which is true for any $r$ and $t$, it is true in particular for $r=m, t=n$.

The essential thing here is that the expression in $r$ and $t$ has been shown to be true for any choice of $r$ and $t$ (or any choice of interest) and does not depend on the original relation with $m$ and $n$.